# Creating a shopping list from an array of ingredients (formatted as objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, javascript-objects

```
var ingredients = [ 
  { name: 'potatoes', quantity: 4 },
  { name: 'butter', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'milk', quantity: 1, description: '1 cup' },
  { name: 'potatoes', quantity: 3 },
  { name: 'oil', quantity: 1, description: '3 cups' } ];

const shoppingList = [];

for (let i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i ++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < shoppingList.length; j ++){
    let ingredient = ingredients[i];
    let shoppingListItem = shoppingList[j];
    if(ingredient === shoppingListItem){
      break;
    }else if (roughDraftItem.name === shoppingListItem.name){
      shoppingListItem.quantity += roughDraftItem.quantity;
      } else {shoppingList.push(roughDraftItem);
        }
    }
  }
```

When I run this code the shoppingList array comes back empty. When I take out the second loop the code doesn't have a problem and I get what I need

```
shoppingListItem = { name: 'potatoes', quantity: 1}
```

It seems to be a problem of trying to compare the Ingredients array to the shoppingList array (after an object has been added).

Comment: The inner loop will not run at all, since `shoppingList` starts out with a `length` of 0, and `0 < 0` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `shoppingList` is empty so its `length = 0`. The second loop of the array doesn't run, since it's told to run `0` times.

You don't need the second loop to add an object to the `shoppingList`, so I would remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `shoppingList` starts with a length of 0, so the 2nd loop will never run. Also, if you're trying to sum the quantity of items with the same name, you could use `reduce` to simplify things:

```js
const ingredients = [ 
  { name: 'potatoes', quantity: 4 },
  { name: 'butter', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'milk', quantity: 1, description: '1 cup' },
  { name: 'potatoes', quantity: 3 },
  { name: 'oil', quantity: 1, description: '3 cups' } ];
  
const result = ingredients.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const exists = acc.find(item => item.name === curr.name);
  if (exists) {
    exists.quantity += curr.quantity;
    return acc;
  }
  return [...acc, curr]
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question was does the [...acc, curr] mean? I don't understand the ... syntax and since I don't know the name of it my google search isn't bringing up an answer

Comment: Also, I see how the reduce will work with this array since potatoes is the only one that repeats. But would it work if I had multiple duplicates? (i.e. two butters, two milks, etc)

Comment: `acc` and `curr` refer to [accumulator and current value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` and ES6 object destructuring assignment to make an aggregation of ingredients by their name, and `Array.prototype.map` to generate the desired output:

This solution is more declarative than nested `for` loops and can work with any amount of repetitive items:

```
var ingredients = [ 
  { name: 'potatoes', quantity: 4 },
  { name: 'butter', quantity: 1 },
  { name: 'milk', quantity: 1, description: '1 cup' },
  { name: 'potatoes', quantity: 3 },
  { name: 'oil', quantity: 1, description: '3 cups' }
];

// Aggregate `quantity` by `name`
var dataObj = ingredients.reduce((all, {name, quantity}) => {
    all[name] = (all[name] || 0) + quantity;
    return all;
}, {});

// Generate the result
var shoppingList = Object.keys(dataObj).map(ing => ({name: ing, quantity: dataObj[ing]}));

console.log(shoppingList);
```